# How to call a function from inside an object and reuse the function in other parts of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that uses a function inside the object to return a value. I want to use the same function in other areas of my code. Can I have the function outside of the object and simply call it?

I've tried creating the function outside of the object and then calling it but isn't working for me. This code works fine

```
var split_object = {
    all: {
        h2_name:"Enterprise view",
    },
    impact_overall: {
        h2_name: function impactHeader() {
            var splitOpts = $('#splitBy option:selected').text();
            var impactOpts = $('#changeImpact option:selected').text();
              if (splitOpts == 'Split by Impact') {
                return impactOpts;
              }
        }
    },
}
```

I tried pulling the function out on it's own and calling it like this

```
impact_overall: {
    h2_name: impactHeader();
    },
```

Comment: Do `impact_overall.h2_name.impactHeader()` or `impact_overall["h2_name"]["impactHeader"]()`. Learn about the dot operator and the square brackets operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
`impact_overall: {
    h2_name: impactHeader();
    },`
```

with this:

```
`impact_overall: {
    h2_name: function() {impactHeader();}
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added unnecessary semicolon

```
impact_overall: {
    h2_name: impactHeader(); // <-- Here
},
```

Just remove it

Answer (score 0):

To reuse the code in the object, you can use context switching. you can achieve this by the following example.

Here getA() in obj is reused with otherObj.

```
var obj = {
  a:'value',
  getA: function(){
    return this.a;
  }
};

var otherObj = {a:'different value'};

obj.getA() // "value"

obj.getA.call(otherObj) // "different value"
```